# Редактирование путей (как значение переменной) в текстовых файлах Apache Ant

Tags: ant

Есть ли в Apache Ant возможность в текстовом файле в определенном месте выставить определенное же значение?

UPD: Мне нужно редактировать значения переменных в JS-файле, причем в зависимости от итоговой конкретной папки.

Например, есть файл build.js. Мы добавляем его в разные папки и в зависимости от конкретной выставляется определенное значение в переменную.

Answer (score 0):

Да, вполне. Вот пример обычного *build.xml* файла для сборки Ant'ом проекта:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="myproject" default="make.production">

    <!--Тут создаются свойства для указания путей-->
    <dirname property="project.dir" file="${ant.file}"/>
    <property name="project.name" value="myproject"/>
    <property name="project.output.dir" location="${project.dir}/classes/production/${project.name}"/>

    <!--Тут они используются-->
    <target name="make.javacode.compile" description="compile module">
        <delete dir="${project.output.dir}"/>
        ...
    </target>

</project>
```

Таким образом, вы как бы объявляете переменные, указывающие на пути, в первой части файла (там, где создаются свойства для указания путей), и значение этих переменных можно выставить в определенное значение и редактировать, а содержимое  файла далее менять не потребуется.

Comment: Мне нужно редактировать значение переменных в JS-файле, причем в зависимости от итоговой конкретной папки. Именно об этом и был вопрос.

Comment: Для замены в строке файла используй Ant task replace https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html